# What is the proper way to test a hibernate dialect?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, testing

I have written my own hibernate dialect for a RDBMS. What is the best way to test the dialect? Are there any testsuites/tests that could be helpful for me? What is the best way to make sure, that my implementation is correct/supports all necessary features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>This is purely from reading stuff from the Hibernate GitHub repos, not from experience with "doing" Hibernate testing.  However, it may be sufficient to get you started ...</sup>

The Hibernate matrix testing framework allows you to run tests against specific database backends; see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-matrix-testing.  The `README.md` file says how to configure the framework for a specific database.

The Hibernate ORM tree includes a number of tests for the core of Hibernate; see https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm.  The `README.md` for that project mentions Gradle tasks for running the tests.  (I haven't looked at the available tests in detail, but since the ORM tree includes the "dialect" classes for a range of database, I would imagine that includes the corresponding tests.)

Hibernate's build and test framework is implemented using Gradle, so I expect that you will need to get your head around that technology to figure out how it all works.

Comment: Absolutely correct! I've done all that you suggested, and that is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any such suite or tests. To start with:

- test various query scenarios & see if queries generated are running fine for that DB - when ran standalone.
- test exceptions expected in all scenarios.
- check on how it behaves for a new/old version of the DB driver.

Best of luck!